# Edit emmeans' arrow plot's facet text

Tags: r, ggplot2, lm, emmeans

I'm trying to edit the facet label's text produced by emmean's arrow plot using ggplot2's syntax to override the default.

```
pigs.lm <- lm(log(conc) ~ source + as.factor(percent),
 data = pigs)
    
pigs.plot <- plot(emmeans(pigs.lm , specs = "percent", by="source"), comparison = T)
```

[image]

```
protein_names <- list('source: fish'="Source: Fish",
                      'source: soy'="Source: Soybean",
                      'source: skim'="Source: Skim milk")
```

I got an error at this step. How do I fix it?

```
pigs.plot + facet_wrap(~ source, labeller = protein_names)

Error in cbind(labels = list(), list(`{`, if (!is.null(.rows) || !is.null(.cols)) { :  number of rows of matrices must match (see arg 2)
```

I tried `facet_grid`, too, but no luck.

Comment: object ```conc``` where to find it?

Comment: @manro, it's a column in the `pigs` data set that is included with `emmeans`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this too:

**#Custom labels**

```
custom_labels <- as_labeller(function(x){
     return(paste0("Source: ", c("Fish", "Soybean", "Skim milk")))
})
```

**#Making a plot**

```
pigs.plot + facet_wrap(~ source, labeller = custom_labels, strip.position = "right", ncol = 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there.  (1) You need a named vector (I think), not a list; (2) the names of the list should match the elements of the faceting variable, not the already-labeled values (i.e. the strip labels).

```r
pp <- unlist(protein_names)
names(pp) <- gsub("source: ","", names(pp))
pigs.plot + facet_wrap(~ source, labeller = labeller(source = pp), ncol = 1)
```

You could also construct your labels correctly in the first place this way:

```r
capwords <- function(x) gsub("^([a-z])", "\\U\\1", x, perl=TRUE)
s <- levels(pigs$source)
protein_names <- setNames(sprintf("Source: %s", capwords(s)), s)
```

Comment: You outpaced me_(+1) ;) I'm finding how to flip ```facet_wrap``` and also try to add an answer.

Comment: do you mean specifying orientation  with `ncol=1` or `nrow=1` or something else ... ?

Comment: I want to achieve his output (like in question). With ```ncol/nrow``` the look is different.

Comment: I did it. One moment!

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that in many cases where a custom plot is desired, it is more straightforward just to start basically from scratch:

```
plotdat <- plot(emmeans(...), comp = TRUE, plotit = FALSE)
```

Now you have a data frame with every value that is needed to construct the plot. So now plot this information in the way you like, perhaps adding or modifying columns in `plotdat` first.